# Sorting by a field that is not in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am faced with the following problem.
I have 2 entities (simple code):

`class Vehicle(id: UUID, name: String, updatedBy: User)`

`class User(id: UUID)`

I get user names in Cognito service by id. And now i want to add sort to Vehicle table by user name. I am using Spring Data in my project. And I dont know how can i add user name field to repository for sorting.

I look towards to use SPEL for solving my problem, but im not sure that it will help me.

Comment: Is sorting like you want to query from the database using JPA and obtain results sorted based on `username` or do you want to sort a Java object based on `username`?

Comment: @Ryednap I would like to use multiple sort and pagination from jpa.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a map of the user IDs and their names (from Cognito), and a list of `Vehicle`s, you can just sort like so:

```java
final UUID user1Id = UUID.randomUUID();
final UUID user2Id = UUID.randomUUID();
final UUID user3Id = UUID.randomUUID();

final Map<UUID, String> userNameMap = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry(user1Id, "User 1"),
    Map.entry(user2Id, "User 2"),
    Map.entry(user3Id, "User 3")
);

final List<Vehicle> vehicles = List.of(
    new Vehicle(UUID.randomUUID(), "Vehicle 1", new User(user1Id)),
    new Vehicle(UUID.randomUUID(), "Vehicle 2", new User(user2Id)),
    new Vehicle(UUID.randomUUID(), "Vehicle 3", new User(user3Id))
);

final List<Vehicle> sortedVehicles = vehicles.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> userNameMap.get(o.getUpdatedBy().getId())))
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

Comment: Is there a way to use sort in repository layer? Because I have more than 10000 objects in DB. Also I want to use pagination

Comment: You can perform the sort in an implemented repository method. Read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations).

Comment: Thats the problem. I dont know how can i transfer and use Map<UUID, String> field to repository for sorting.